# Multiple Datasets in One Report in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, reporting, datasource

I'm trying to include two sets of data in SSRS 2012.  In my datasource (called DS) I'm pulling two datasets - we'll call them OfficeActivity and Transactions.  Neither dataset has any data relation to the other.  The Transactions dataset is displayed in a table, while the OfficeActivity dataset will be used to populate some fields in the header - e.g. "Total Sales: $XXXXX.XX"

When I create a new SSRS project and use the wizard, I can create the Transactions table without problems, and it runs without a hitch.  The problem is when I try to include the OfficeActivity data.

In the Report Data pane I right-click my DS datasource and choose "Add Dataset...".  I give the new dataset a name, select DS as the datasource, and choose the OfficeActivity dataset under Available Datasets.  The result looks like this:

[image]

The Report Data pane now looks like this:

[image]

However when I attempt to run the report I get the following error:

```
A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dsOA'.
```

Can anybody provide any guidance on why this isn't working?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a possible bug in the wizard to me. Have you tried editing the properties of the dsOA dataset and setting the data source properties again?

Comment: I have; everything shows up as you would expect.  Also I opened the RDLC file in a text editor and it showed both tables listed.  All the connection-related fields were identical.  I suppose I could create all this using code rather than the wizard, but we're planning to convert all of our Crystal reports to SSRS and it would be much easier to use the wizard for all 50-ish reports rather than having to do it in code.